# rename multiple files alphabetical order in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell, unix, rename

In a folder, I have multiple files (about 60K) with random names like this and I want to rename all of them in alphabetically order.

```
jlg6aej.gif  
owu46tljff.JPG  
28LKG.JPG
uoeoo87967.jpg
....
```

I know how to rename them numeritically, like

`ls | cat -n | while read n f; do mv "f" "$n.txt"; done`

right now I want to rename them alphabetically rather than numeritically, so any alphabetical order is fine, but please use only letters, no numbers in file name, for example:

```
aaaa.txt  
aaab.txt  
aaac.txt
aaad.txt  
....
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please show your coding efforts.

Comment: How many files are there?

Comment: it is about 60000 files

Comment: I know how to rename all of them numerically, ls | cat -n |  while read n f; do mv "f"  "$n.txt"; done  right now I want to rename them alphabetically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using only bash

```
a=({a..d}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z})
x=0
for i in *;do echo mv "${i}" "${a[$((x++))]}.${i##*.}";done
```

remove the echo if you are happy with the output.

or with perl

```
perl -e '$prefix="aaaa";map{rename "$_",$prefix++.".$1" if /.*\.(.*)/} <*>'
```

Answer (score 1):

- First, you need to extract all the extensions.
- Then, foreach extension, you must rename all the files, and increment the name.

I've quickly done a Perl script to achieve that, because list support is easier than bash.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = <*>;
my @extensions = map { my ($f) = m/\.(.*?)$/; $f; } @files;

my @unique_ext;
my %seen;

foreach my $value (@extensions) {
    if (! $seen{$value}) {
        push @unique_ext, $value;
        $seen{$value} = 1;
    }
}

use Data::Dumper;

foreach my $current (@unique_ext)
{
    my $start = 'aaaaaa';
    my @file_list = <*$current>;
    foreach my $file (@file_list)
    {
    rename $file, "$start.$current";
    $start ++;
    }
}
```

Still requires improvements, but current that version has renamed all the file (and the perl script as well... :)) in my directory:

```
$ ls
LKG.JPG      jlgaej.gif   owutljff.JPG uoeoo.jpg
$ perl rename.pl
$ ls
aaaaaa.JPG aaaaaa.gif aaaaaa.jpg aaaaaa.pl  aaaaab.JPG
```